# Mejorar expresión regular para validar contraseña

Tags: javascript

Estoy utilizando la librería smoke.js para validar formularios, esta librería cuenta con la opción de validar las contraseñas en cuanto a su tamaño y caracteres que se pueden usar. La expresión regular que utiliza para ese fin es la siguiente :

```
/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])\w{6,}$/
```

Quiero modificarla y hacer que permita caracteres especiales

```
@+-_?¿.#*%&$!¡/\[]{}
```

que tenga una longitud mínima de 10 caracteres,que contenga mínimo una mayúsculas, y mínimo un números y que incluya cualquier otro caracter que el usuario quiera introducir.

Escudriñando un poco encontré esta expresión regular la cual creo yo aplica para lo que necesito pero quiero saber si es segura utilizarla y/o que cambios podría hacer para que sea efectiva al momento de la creación de la contraseña.

```
^(?=^.{10,}$)((?=.*\d)|(?=.*\W+))(?![.\n])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).*$
```

Comment: Todo depende de lo que estés buscando. Esa expresión regular **obliga** a usar ciertos caracteres, mientras que por tus comentarios quieres **permitir**. La pregunta es un poco vaga tal cual está escrita. ¿Es segura? La respuesta es siempre **La validación en el lado del cliente de cualquier dato puede aumentar la usabilidad, nunca la seguridad**

Comment: @PabloLozano, a mi parecer creo que smoke.js se queda un poco corto al momento validar las características que deben cumplir las contraseña y lo que deseo es adaptarla en mi caso para que las contraseñas tengan una longitud mínima de 10 caracteres, que contenga mínimo una mayúsculas, y mínimo un números y que permita incluir caracteres ASCII ya que de momento smoke no lo permite

Comment: @car-onte puedes usar paginas como regex101 para crear tests y ver si la expresion regular pasa o no las contraseñas validas e invalidas.

Comment: Podrías probar una de estas tres [regex (contraseñas)](http://w3.unpocodetodo.info/utiles/regex-ejemplos.php?type=psw)